# Netbeans Broken Platform

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, java-7

How can I specify two names to satisfy a Java dependency?  I'm using Netbeans and by default,  Linux calls OpenJDK "JDK_7".  Windows calls Oracle JDK "JDK 1.7".  I would like to make it so that by default either name is acceptable because my code builds the same on both platforms.

Is there a way to specify a "platform" can be either A or B in Netbeans/ant?

Comment: Add a new platform, pointing to the JDK y want, named they way you want.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that it automatically builds without adding a platform.

Comment: Netbeans needs a platform, it rebuilds the buildimpl.xml file each time you open the project and uses the platform information for the project to generate it.  Unless you're willing to create you own build.xml for ant, I can't see you have any other choice

Comment: May I recommend using maven?  If you use maven, netbeans can open up your project across platforms without much issue, and you can specify things like the JDK version in a much more cross platform way.  For more info see here:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/Maven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two lines in the nbproject/project.properties file

```
platform.active=default_platform
platforms.default_platform.home=${java.home}/../
```

These make the Netbeans Platform choose the default platform as the standard platform.

Answer (score 11):

Right click on the project. Then, select "properties". Select "Libraries" from the categories on the left hand side of Project Properties. And then select the new "Java Platform".